In Django I have been getting this error can anyone help me to solve this
while learning Django created static folder and templates folder and imported code from bootstrap and while running the server I have been getting this errorThis image with Debug = True in settings.py fileAnd this image with Debug = False in settings.py file
I need this to solve my error

Add the below line in the project folder urls.py that points to your main app
path("", RedirectView.as_view(url="/mainapp/", permanent=True)),

In settings.py set ALLOWED_HOSTS=['localhost','127.0.0.1'] and you can read more about ALLOWED_HOSTS from here
